# How to add focus and flash support to camera

Tags: xaml, flash, camera, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I'm programming for windows phone 8.1 and built a basic camera using MediaCapture (Windows.Media.Capture).
How can I add focus and flash to the camera? This is my current code:

```
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.Landscape;
        width = Convert.ToInt32(Window.Current.Bounds.Width);
        height = Convert.ToInt32(Window.Current.Bounds.Height);
        capturePreview.Width = width;
        capturePreview.Height = height;
        Starter();
    }
    async private void Starter()
    {
        captureManager = new MediaCapture();
        await captureManager.InitializeAsync();
        StartCapturePreview_Click();
    }

    async private void StartCapturePreview_Click()
    {
        capturePreview.Source = captureManager;
        await captureManager.StartPreviewAsync();
    }

    async private void StopCapturePreview_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await captureManager.StopPreviewAsync();
    }

    //private void focus_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    //{
        //FocusManager.TryMoveFocus(FocusNavigationDirection.Next);

    //}

    async private void CapturePhoto_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageEncodingProperties imgFormat = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();

        // create storage file in local app storage 
        StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(
            "Photo.jpg",
            CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        // take photo 
        await captureManager.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(imgFormat, file);

        // Get photo as a BitmapImage 
        BitmapImage bmpImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(file.Path));

        // imagePreivew is a <Image> object defined in XAML 
        imagePreview.Source = bmpImage;
    }
```

What is the best way to add focus and a flash? I tried using the FocusManager but didn't succeed in working with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't help you with the flash, but for focus I use this on WP8.1RT:

```
private async void focus_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        await captureManager.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.UnlockAsync();
        var focusSettings = new FocusSettings();
        focusSettings.AutoFocusRange = AutoFocusRange.Normal;
        focusSettings.Mode = FocusMode.Auto;
        focusSettings.WaitForFocus = true;
        focusSettings.DisableDriverFallback = false;
        captureManager.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.Configure(focusSettings);
        await captureManager.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.FocusAsync();
    }
    catch {}
}
```

You may want to add a rectangle to your *capturePreview* so you can see on which object you are focussing.
I don't know the exact size but on my phone (Lumia 520 with a 4" screen) in landscape orientation, it seems the camera is using an area of approximately 150 by 100 pixels in the center of the *capturePreview*.

Comment: It seems the camera is taking p the whole capture preview, is there a way for me to make the focus work also by manually pressing on the area I want focused?

Comment: I'm not sure. I only found out it's focussing on objects in the center of the screen. I tested this by taking pictures of my hand and see which fingerprints and handlines were the clearest.  Only the parts in the center are. Then added a rectangle to see how far away from the center an object can be before it's not focussing on it anymore. I don't think the focus area can be moved.

Comment: How do you add a rectangle to see focus area?

Comment: The rectangle by itself doesn't do anything. It's only used to display the area the camera will use to focus. Just add this to your xaml: **<Rectangle Name="focusarea" Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="1" Width="130" Height="130" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed"/>**. Note: a width and height of 130 seem sufficient, but you may mant to experiment with it. I have the rectangle hidden until the focusbutten is used. And hide it again when the button is released.

Comment: It doesn't. I don't think there is a way to show the focus area.  In my app I only found out by trail-and-error by focussing on different objects from different angles, distances from the camera and different distances from the center of the screen. After analysing the pictures I made an educated guess about the approximate focus area, then added the rectangle. Then took more pictures with objects in, near and on the border of the rectangle and adjusted the rectangle size when needed. The rectangle is just a visual indicator so the user can see where the focus area is supposed to be.

Comment: Here's all one needs to implement tap to focus etc: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/CameraManualControls/cs/MainPage.Focus.xaml.cs

Answer (score 0):

You can add flash by doing:             `_captureManager.VideoDeviceController.FlashControl.AssistantLightEnabled = false/true;`